# URL for background property disappearing when CSS loads

Tags: css, url, background, background-image

i am having the weirdest CSS issue. my CSS works fine on my localhost server, but when I load it onto a live server, the "url" in the background property disappears.

Here is the HTML - very basic div:
    <div id="header-wrapper"> </div>

Here is the CSS from my working file:

```
#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('../images/bgblue.jpg') repeat-x left top;
}
```

Here is what shows up when I view page source on the live site:

```
#header-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    background: 

    (images/bgblue.jpg) repeat-x left top;
}
```

As you can see the "url" portion has disappeared. What is extra weird is that the div right after this one has the exact same format and is displaying fine.
HELP! Thank you!

Comment: There shouldnt be any ' ' marks around the URL. Perhaps that is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

If it is the "exact" same format, the next div you mentioned should have the same id. Id should be used once in a page.

I do not know if this would help or not but try `background-image: url` instead.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
#header-wrapper {
overflow: hidden;
height: 300px;
background: url(/images/bgblue.jpg) repeat-x left top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this problem, where the style doesn't show on the live page. It usually happens when there is a syntax error, the browser doesn't load that rule, therefore Firebug does not even display it. Clear cache and go to the url of the .css file, make sure it is sending the expected code. If so there is a syntax error.